# converting a text file to csv file with out index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a testx file with data

```
1 1 1 1 1 
2
3 4 4 4 4
```

want to read this as a csv file.

```
data = pd.read_csv("file.txt",sep="\n",header=none)
```

but this is adding

```
   0,
    1,1 1 1 1 1 
    2,2
    3,3 4 4 4 4
```

ow can I remove index and not the , so that I can get a csv file.

of I write `index=false` the comma is also gone

I am looking output as

```
,1 1 1 1 1 
,2
,3 4 4 4 4
```

because my input prohram takes only csv files

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: I have added the expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from io import StringIO

csvtext = StringIO("""1 1 1 1 1 
2
3 4 4 4 4""")

data = pd.read_csv(csvtext, sep='\n', header=None)

data.to_csv('out.csv', index=False, header=False)

#on windows

!type out.csv
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 
2
3 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: I want , also .

Comment: @MLlearner with the same code, open the output file in notepad od notepad++ ?

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding you, i think you only need to read it without altering it, try this:

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', newline='') as txt_file:
    csv_file = csv.reader(txt_file, delimiter=' ')

    #if you need to convert it to csv file:
    with open ('file.csv', "w",newline='') as new_csv_file:
        new_csv = csv.writer(new_csv_file, delimiter=',')

        for row in csv_file:
            print(' '.join(row))
            new_csv.writerow(row)
```

Output on csv format (Your expected output is **not** [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)):

```
1,1,1,1,1,
2
3,4,4,4,4
```

I have edited the answer so if you want to write a csv file, now you can with the previous code. You can work around formats using the [dialects and formatting parameters](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) of csv module.

Comment: There are comma after every number, I want to separate this file as a comma separated only

Comment: @MLlearner you can change the delimiter to wichever you prefer, even white spaces